# Add custom Text to uibutton in iPhone sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I want to use uibutton which has custom text like screen shot shows. In screen shot I added 2 uilabel to text "Module 1" and "Fungi & Fungal Infections" but and orange background is uibutton but when I press down is it shows that It only press orange button and not text. What I want that I'll set these to label to uibutton text so that It'll show that when button press down then text should have same effect like button's title[image: Fungi Image]. How this possible kindly guide me on this, this will be great for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: better way to set image as you shown

Comment: No, I don't want to use image. Is there any possibility to achieve this target?

Answer (score 2):

Is easy, just create label with attributed text that you want and add it to uiButton as subview, like this. Button set to custom type in storyboard.

```
UILabel * label = [UILabel new];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
label.text = @"Custom text";
[label sizeToFit];
label.frame = _button.bounds;
[_button addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select UIButton type custom
and uncheck 'Highlight adjusts image' 
You can refer this image
It will help you. :) 
[image: Restrict UIButton Highlight state]